# Breakpoints not hit in IntelliJ 2020.3

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Problem: the IntelliJ Debugger doesn't stop at any breakpoints in Java code.

Details: using version 2020.3. It was fine last week but it could be there was an update over the weekend that caused this problem.

What didn't work: Unmuting breakpoints, disabling then enabling breakpoints, restarting IntelliJ after Invalidating cache, deleting .idea folder.

Eventually I solved it. See solution below.

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me was opening .idea/workspace.xml, finding the specific Run/Debug Configuration I'm trying to debug, then changing `<DebugAllEnabled>false</DebugAllEnabled>` to `<DebugAllEnabled>true</DebugAllEnabled>`.